# How to type annotate optionally parametrized decorator, which use third party decorator inside

Tags: python, decorator, mypy, python-typing

Faced with problem, when using `mypy` on my project. At first I use a `backoff` package to do some retries on some functions/methods. Then I realised, that most of options are just repeated, so I created per-project decorator, with all common values filled for `backoff` decorator. But, I don't know how to annotate such "decorator in decorator". More to say, this should work with sync/async function/method matrix. Here is code to reproduce my pain:

```py
import asyncio
from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Literal, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")
AnyCallable = Callable[P, T | Awaitable[T]]
Decorator = Callable[[AnyCallable[P, T]], AnyCallable[P, T]]


def third_party_decorator(
        a: int | None = None,
        b: str | None = None,
        c: Literal[None] = None,
        d: bool | None = None,
        e: str | None = None,
    ) -> Decorator[P, T]:
    def decorator(f: AnyCallable[P, T]) -> AnyCallable[P, T]:
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T | Awaitable[T]:
            print(f"third_party_decorator {f = } {a = } {b = } {c = } {d = } {e = }")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def parametrized_decorator(f: AnyCallable[P, T] | None = None, **kwargs: Any) -> Decorator[P, T] | AnyCallable[P, T]:
    def decorator(f: AnyCallable[P, T]) -> AnyCallable[P, T]:
        defaults = {"a": 1, "b": "b", "c": None, "d": True}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        print(f"parametrized_decorator {f = } {defaults = }")
        decorator: Decorator[P, T] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
        wrapped = decorator(f)
        return wrapped

    if f is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(f)


@parametrized_decorator
def sync_straight_function(x: int = 0) -> None:
    print(f"sync_straight_function {x = }")


@parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
def sync_parametrized_function(x: str = "abc", y: bool = False) -> None:
    print(f"sync_parametrized_function {x = } {y = }")


@parametrized_decorator
async def async_straight_function(x: int = 0) -> None:
    print(f"sync_straight_function {x = }")


@parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
async def async_parametrized_function(x: str = "abc", y: bool = False) -> None:
    print(f"sync_parametrized_function {x = } {y = }")


class Foo:
    @parametrized_decorator
    def sync_straight_method(self, x: int = 0) -> None:
        print(f"sync_straight_function {x = }")

    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
    def sync_parametrized_method(self, x: str = "abc", y: bool = False) -> None:
        print("sync_parametrized_method", x, y)

    @parametrized_decorator
    async def async_straight_method(self, x: int = 0) -> None:
        print(f"sync_straight_function {x = }")

    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
    async def async_parametrized_method(self, x: str = "abc", y: bool = False) -> None:
        print(f"sync_parametrized_function {x = } {y = }")


def main_sync_functions() -> None:
    sync_straight_function()
    sync_straight_function(1)

    sync_parametrized_function()
    sync_parametrized_function("xyz", True)


async def main_async_functions() -> None:
    await async_straight_function()
    await async_straight_function(1)

    await async_parametrized_function()
    await async_parametrized_function("xyz", True)


def main_sync_methods() -> None:
    foo = Foo()
    foo.sync_straight_method()
    foo.sync_straight_method(1)

    foo.sync_parametrized_method()
    foo.sync_parametrized_method("xyz", True)


async def main_async_methods() -> None:
    foo = Foo()
    await foo.async_straight_method()
    await foo.async_straight_method(1)

    await foo.async_parametrized_method()
    await foo.async_parametrized_method("xyz", True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\nSYNC FUNCTIONS:")
    main_sync_functions()
    print("\nASYNC FUNCTIONS:")
    asyncio.run(main_async_functions())
    print("\nSYNC METHODS:")
    main_sync_methods()
    print("\nASYNC METHODS:")
    asyncio.run(main_async_methods())
```

The output of mypy have 44 errors:

```
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:33: error: Argument 1 to "third_party_decorator" has incompatible type "**dict[str, object]"; expected "int | None"  [arg-type]
            decorator: Decorator[P, T] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:33: error: Argument 1 to "third_party_decorator" has incompatible type "**dict[str, object]"; expected "str | None"  [arg-type]
            decorator: Decorator[P, T] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:33: error: Argument 1 to "third_party_decorator" has incompatible type "**dict[str, object]"; expected "None"  [arg-type]
            decorator: Decorator[P, T] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:33: error: Argument 1 to "third_party_decorator" has incompatible type "**dict[str, object]"; expected "bool | None"  [arg-type]
            decorator: Decorator[P, T] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:48: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[str, bool], None]"; expected
"Callable[[VarArg(<nothing>), KwArg(<nothing>)], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
     ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:48: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[str, bool], None]"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
     ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:53: error: Argument 1 to "parametrized_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected
"Callable[[int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | None"  [arg-type]
    @parametrized_decorator
     ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:58: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[str, bool], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected
"Callable[[VarArg(<nothing>), KwArg(<nothing>)], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
     ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:58: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[str, bool], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
    @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
     ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:68: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, str, bool], None]"; expected
"Callable[[VarArg(<nothing>), KwArg(<nothing>)], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
        @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
         ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:68: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, str, bool], None]"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
         ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:72: error: Argument 1 to "parametrized_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, int], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected
"Callable[[Foo, int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | None"  [arg-type]
        @parametrized_decorator
         ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:76: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, str, bool], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected
"Callable[[VarArg(<nothing>), KwArg(<nothing>)], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
        @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
         ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:76: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, str, bool], Coroutine[Any, Any, None]]"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        @parametrized_decorator(b="B", e="e")
         ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:82: error: Too few arguments  [call-arg]
        sync_straight_function()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:83: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Callable[[int], Awaitable[None] | None]"  [arg-type]
        sync_straight_function(1)
                               ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:85: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        sync_parametrized_function()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:86: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        sync_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:86: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        sync_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
                                   ^~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:86: error: Argument 2 has incompatible type "bool"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        sync_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
                                          ^~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:90: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Callable[[int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | Awaitable[<nothing>]",
expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
        await async_straight_function()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:90: error: Too few arguments  [call-arg]
        await async_straight_function()
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:91: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Callable[[int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | Awaitable[<nothing>]",
expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
        await async_straight_function(1)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:91: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Callable[[int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
        await async_straight_function(1)
                                      ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:93: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        await async_parametrized_function()
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:94: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        await async_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:94: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        await async_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
                                          ^~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:94: error: Argument 2 has incompatible type "bool"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        await async_parametrized_function("xyz", True)
                                                 ^~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:99: error: Too few arguments  [call-arg]
        foo.sync_straight_method()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:100: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Callable[[Foo, int], Awaitable[None] | None]"  [arg-type]
        foo.sync_straight_method(1)
                                 ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:100: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Foo"  [arg-type]
        foo.sync_straight_method(1)
                                 ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:102: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        foo.sync_parametrized_method()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:103: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        foo.sync_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:103: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        foo.sync_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
                                     ^~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:103: error: Argument 2 has incompatible type "bool"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        foo.sync_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
                                            ^~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:108: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Callable[[Foo, int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | Awaitable[<nothing>]",
expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
        await foo.async_straight_method()
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:108: error: Too few arguments  [call-arg]
        await foo.async_straight_method()
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:109: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Callable[[Foo, int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]] | Awaitable[<nothing>]",
expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
        await foo.async_straight_method(1)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:109: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Callable[[Foo, int], <nothing> | Awaitable[<nothing>]]"  [arg-type]
        await foo.async_straight_method(1)
                                        ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:109: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Foo"  [arg-type]
        await foo.async_straight_method(1)
                                        ^
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:111: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        await foo.async_parametrized_method()
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:112: error: "Awaitable[<nothing>]" not callable  [operator]
        await foo.async_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:112: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        await foo.async_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
                                            ^~~~~
parametrized-decorator-typing.py:112: error: Argument 2 has incompatible type "bool"; expected <nothing>  [arg-type]
        await foo.async_parametrized_method("xyz", True)
                                                   ^~~~
Found 44 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you proposed has one major flaw: your `parametrized_decorator` destroys the function signature. You still need a typevar to preserve it.

First of all, your `T` does not have any bound, so `Awaitable[Something]` can also be just `T`. In your `third_party_decorator`, `wrapper` returns `T | Awaitable[T]` which is just weird - it always returns the given `T`, it can't become more awaitable. So, we can forget about `Awaitable` here entirely, and this greatly simplifies the typing.

Then, your decorator can behave in two different ways: either be a 2nd-order deco (return a decorator) when func is not passed, or return a function otherwise. This can be expressed as an `overload`. Here's what I suggest ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=0b2017fe5e2eedcf25ab074aa9fa4c3c)):

```py
import asyncio
from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable, Coroutine
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Literal, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
_T1 = TypeVar("_T1")
P = ParamSpec("P")
_P1 = ParamSpec("_P1")



def third_party_decorator(
        a: int | None = None,
        b: str | None = None,
        c: Literal[None] = None,
        d: bool | None = None,
        e: str | None = None,
    ) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    def decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            print(f"third_party_decorator {f = } {a = } {b = } {c = } {d = } {e = }")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@overload
def parametrized_decorator(f: None = ..., /, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]: ...
@overload
def parametrized_decorator(f: Callable[P, T], /, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable[P, T]: ...
def parametrized_decorator(f: Callable[P, T] | None = None, /, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable[[Callable[_P1, _T1]], Callable[_P1, _T1]] | Callable[P, T]:
    def decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        defaults = {"a": 1, "b": "b", "c": None, "d": True}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        print(f"parametrized_decorator {f = } {defaults = }")
        decorator = third_party_decorator(**defaults)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
        wrapped = decorator(f)
        return wrapped

    if f is None:
        # You can avoid type-ignore here, but this will require an insane if
        # clause with `decorator` body effectively repeated twice
        return decorator  # type: ignore[return-value]
    else:
        return decorator(f)
```

Note the ugly `_T1` and `_P1` above? It's because callable is generic itself, and binds too early (`P` and `T` should be the same in the left side and in both sides of a new callable). Let's fix this by making "alternative Callable" which is not generic, but provides a generic `__call__` only ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=8a69e541fb65c5517d33c95266632878)):

```py
import asyncio
from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable, Coroutine
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Literal, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload, Protocol

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


class Decorator(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, func: Callable[P, T], /) -> Callable[P, T]: ...


def third_party_decorator(
        a: int | None = None,
        b: str | None = None,
        c: Literal[None] = None,
        d: bool | None = None,
        e: str | None = None,
    ) -> Decorator:
    def decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            print(f"third_party_decorator {f = } {a = } {b = } {c = } {d = } {e = }")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@overload
def parametrized_decorator(f: None = ..., /, **kwargs: Any) -> Decorator: ...
@overload
def parametrized_decorator(f: Callable[P, T], /, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable[P, T]: ...
def parametrized_decorator(f: Callable[P, T] | None = None, /, **kwargs: Any) -> Decorator | Callable[P, T]:
    def decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        defaults = {"a": 1, "b": "b", "c": None, "d": True}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        print(f"parametrized_decorator {f = } {defaults = }")
        decorator = third_party_decorator(**defaults)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
        wrapped = decorator(f)
        return wrapped

    if f is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(f)
```

And now you don't have any ignore comments and have proper return types.

To explain my "destroys the signature",  `reveal_type(sync_straight_function)` or just try `sync_straight_function('this', 'is', 'still', 'allowed', 'why?') + 1` with the implementation from your answer and observe no mypy errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ended up with code below. Do not mind `type: ignore`, since this is third party decorator.

```py
AnyCallable = Callable[..., Any]
F = TypeVar("F", bound=AnyCallable)
Decorator = Callable[[F], F]


def third_party_decorator(
        a: int | None = None,
        b: str | None = None,
        c: Literal[None] = None,
        d: bool | None = None,
        e: str | None = None,
    ) -> Decorator[F]:
    def decorator(f: F) -> F:
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            print(f"third_party_decorator {f = } {a = } {b = } {c = } {d = } {e = }")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper  # type: ignore
    return decorator


def parametrized_decorator(f: AnyCallable | None = None, **kwargs: Any) -> AnyCallable:
    def decorator(f: F) -> F:
        defaults: dict[str, Any] = {"a": 1, "b": "b", "c": None, "d": True}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        print(f"parametrized_decorator {f = } {defaults = }")
        decorator: Decorator[F] = third_party_decorator(**defaults)
        wrapped = decorator(f)
        return wrapped

    if f is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(f)
```